# linux /tmp folder + how to know if files will deleted after reboot or after some time

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, tmp

I have Linux red-hat machine
And I not sure what the concept about the directory /tmp

How to know if the files under  /tmp will deleted after reboot or maybe will deleted after some time

Which file/configuration in my Linux machine responsible for that ?
And if it possible to change the rules there?

remark my crontab is empty - no deleted Job there

Comment: Why do you ask? Are you afraid of a `/tmp/` full of rubbish, or of your program losing files under `/tmp/` ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is specified in the [File Hierarchy Standard](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb/fhs) and [Linux Standard Base](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/lsb.shtml)

`/tmp/` is often [`tmpfs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) mounted, and on systems where it is not the case, the boot init scripts should (and usually do) clean it.

So files under `/tmp/` do not survive a reboot. Put them elsewhere (perhaps `/var/tmp/`) if you want them to survive a reboot.

---

In the [FHS §2.3](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#TMPTEMPORARYFILES):

> The /tmp directory must be made available for programs that require temporary files.
>
> Programs must not assume that any files or directories in /tmp are preserved between invocations of the program.
>
> Tip   Rationale
>
> IEEE standard P1003.2 (POSIX, part 2) makes requirements that are similar to the above section.
>
> Although data stored in /tmp may be deleted in a site-specific manner, it is recommended that files and directories located in /tmp be deleted whenever the system is booted.

---

So unless your systems are very badly misconfigured, you should presume that `/tmp/` is cleaned at least at reboot time. BTW, some sysadmins are setting a `crontab` entry to clean old files (e.g. weekly clean older than 2 weeks file). See also [tmpfiles.d(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfiles.d.5.html), [TMPDIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMPDIR), [mkstemp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html), [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html), POSIX [tmpfile](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tmpfile.html) & [tmpnam](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tmpnam.html)

Answer (score 4):

Just check the output of

```
mount
```

If you find that `/tmp` is of `tmpfs` type, then it will be deleted. `tmpfs` is an in-memory filesystem.

But never count on `/tmp` to persist.

Comment: BTW, many boot init scripts are cleaning `/tmp/` if it is not of `tmpfs` type. So you should assume that files under `/tmp/` won't survive reboots.

Comment: good point Basile - so how to verify in my linux machine which boot script will remove my files ?

Answer (score 1):

> **systemctl cat systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer**

```
# /lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer
#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1-or-later
#
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories
Documentation=man:tmpfiles.d(5) man:systemd-tmpfiles(8)
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/initrd-release

[Timer]
OnBootSec=15min
OnUnitActiveSec=1d
```

The `[Timer]` section specifies what service to trigger (`systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer`) and when to trigger it. In this case, the option `OnBootSec` specifies a monotonic timer that triggers the service 5 minutes after the system boot, while the option `OnUnitActiveSec` triggers the service 24 hours after the service has been activated (that is, the timer will trigger the service once a day).

Answer (score 0):

The default setting that tells your system to clear /tmp at reboot is held in the /etc/default/rcS file.

```
The value we’ll look at is TMPTIME.The current value of TMPTIME=0 says delete files at reboot despite the age of the file.Changing this value to a different (positive) number will change the number of days a file can survive in /tmp.
```

Code:

```
TMPTIME=7
```

This setting would allow files to stay in /tmp until they are a week old, and then delete them on the next reboot.

A negative number (

```
TMPTIME=-1
```

) tells the system to never delete anything in /tmp.